# Apache won't start with added VirtualHost, but gives no error in error log

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am using EasyPHP (version 16.1.1) for Apache server (installed version 2.4.18 x86). I need to add a new VirtualHost, so now the whole VirtualHost section of httpd.conf looks like this:

```
# VIRTUAL HOSTS
## Virtualhost localweb
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www"
ServerName 127.0.0.1
<Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerAdmin marekbuchtela@gmail.com
ServerName posis
ServerAlias posis.tovarna
VirtualDocumentRoot "C:\Users\marek\is\tovarna\public"
</VirtualHost>
```

The first one is the default one made by EasyPHP, the second one is added by me. However in this setup, the Apache won't start. When I remove the second VirtualHost, everything works fine, but with it, it just won't start at all. I have checked the error log and there is no output at all.

Any ideas why is this happening/how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: do not mix Allow/Order directives with Require directives, that's a recipe for disaster. In 2.4 use only Require directives and unload mod_access_compat.

Comment: For Googlers: In my case, the problem was that I had there a **`Listen` directive for an IP that was no longer assigned to my pc**. When I removed this from config, it started working: `Listen 192.168.4.151:80`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch `VirtualDocumentRoot "C:\Users\marek\is\tovarna\public"`for `DocumentRoot "C:\Users\marek\is\tovarna\public"`

If by any chance you keep getting the error, show error_log output

Answer (score 0):

There is another instance other than the answer given by ezra-s as to why EasyPHP server won't start and the Apache error log is empty.

When declaring paths in the vhosts file, it is important that the directories referenced in those paths exist. If you provide the following `VirtualHost` information, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/MyApp/public_html"
    ServerName myapp.local
    ErrorLog "D:/MyApp/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "D:/MyApp/logs/apache.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

...but you don't have a `D:` drive, or the directories `D:/MyApp/` and `D:/MyApp/logs/` don't exist, then you'll get a "silent fail" in Apache when starting the HTTP server from the EasyPHP console.